# Struct for money and currencies

Tags: c#

There are a few of these out there. Some seemed a little convoluted. Maybe mine is too. This is for real-world use.

Here's the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/scotthannen/Plasticfloor.Money) with unit tests. I'm updating that, not the code submitted here for review.

A few notes:

- I went back and forth on whether to use an `enum` or `int` for ISO4217 currency codes because enums can be trouble for WCF services. I settled on `enum` because currency isn't an `int`. I included a `MoneyDto` (omitted here) with an `int` although possibly I'll never use it.
- I haven't explored concerns about rounding yet. For now I'll plan on rounding when needed. `Price` will be a later abstraction. I'll round the amount when forming a `Price` to avoid trailing fractions. (If an item costs $.01, you shouldn't see an extra penny when you buy 100 because $.01 was really $.0101.) But that's for later.
- I customized the XML serialization because it contained autogenerated backing field names and that's lame.
- **Update 6/15/2017** - I considered modifying `CompareTo` to allow sorting and comparisons between mismatched currencies. Then I bought a copy of Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Architecture and saw that he handles it exactly the same way I did - throwing an exception if the currencies don't match. So now I feel pretty good about it!

Thanks for any feedback.

```
[Serializable]
public struct Money : IComparable<Money>, IComparable, IXmlSerializable
{
    public Money(decimal amount, Currencies currency)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }

    public Currencies Currency { get; private set; }

    public Money ToAmount(decimal amount) => new Money(amount, Currency);

    #region Math

    public Money Add(decimal add) => new Money(Amount + add, Currency);

    public Money Subtract(decimal subtract) => new Money(Amount - subtract, Currency);

    public Money Multiply(decimal by) => new Money(Amount * by, Currency);

    public Money Divide(decimal by) => new Money(Amount / by, Currency);

    public static Money operator +(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return new Money(m1.Amount + m2.Amount, m1.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator -(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return new Money(m1.Amount - m2.Amount, m1.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator +(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return new Money(m.Amount + d, m.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator -(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return new Money(m.Amount - d, m.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator +(decimal d, Money m)
    {
        return new Money(m.Amount + d, m.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator -(decimal d, Money m)
    {
        return new Money(m.Amount - d, m.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator *(Money m1, decimal d)
    {
        return new Money(m1.Amount * d, m1.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator /(Money m1, decimal d)
    {
        return new Money(m1.Amount / d, m1.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator *(Money m1, long l)
    {
        return new Money(m1.Amount * l, m1.Currency);
    }

    public static Money operator /(Money m1, long l)
    {
        return new Money(m1.Amount / l, m1.Currency);
    }

    public Money Round()
    {
        return new Money(decimal.Round(Amount), Currency);
    }

    public Money Round(int decimals)
    {
        return new Money(decimal.Round(Amount, decimals), Currency);
    }

    public Money Round(MidpointRounding mode)
    {
        return new Money(decimal.Round(Amount, mode), Currency);
    }

    public Money Round(int decimals, MidpointRounding mode)
    {
        return new Money(decimal.Round(Amount, decimals, mode), Currency);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Comparison

    public bool Equals(Money other)
    {
        return Amount == other.Amount && Currency == other.Currency;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is Money && Equals((Money)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // Amount and Currency are not read-only but are only
            // set by the constructor or deserialization.
            return (Amount.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ (int)Currency;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Money other)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(this, other);
        return Amount.CompareTo(other.Amount);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        if (obj is Money) return CompareTo((Money)obj);
        throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot compare type {obj.GetType()} to type Money.");
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return m1.Amount.Equals(m2.Amount);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return !m1.Amount.Equals(m2.Amount);
    }

    public static bool operator >(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return m1.Amount > m2.Amount;
    }

    public static bool operator <(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return m1.Amount < m2.Amount;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return m1.Amount >= m2.Amount;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);
        return m1.Amount <= m2.Amount;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return m.Amount > d;
    }

    public static bool operator <(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return m.Amount < d;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return m.Amount >= d;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(Money m, decimal d)
    {
        return m.Amount <= d;
    }

    public int CompareTo(decimal d)
    {
        return Amount.CompareTo(d);
    }

    #endregion

    #region XmlSerialization

    private const string XmlAmountAttribute = "amount";
    private const string CurrencyAttribute = "currency";

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute(XmlAmountAttribute), out decimal amount)
            && Enum.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute(CurrencyAttribute), out Currencies currency))
        {
            Amount = amount;
            Currency = currency;
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString(XmlAmountAttribute, Amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        writer.WriteAttributeString(CurrencyAttribute, Currency.ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    public static void RequireSameCurrency(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        if (!m1.Currency.Equals(m2.Currency))
            throw new CurrencyMismatchException(m1.Currency, m2.Currency);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not intended for UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(Amount.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture), " ", Currency.ToString());
    }
}

public enum Currencies
{
    Unknown = 0,
    // The actual enum contains all of them. Cut out for brevity.
    [Description("Canadian dollar")] CAD = 124,      
    [Description("Euro")] EUR = 978,
    [Description("United States dollar")] USD = 840
}

public class CurrencyMismatchException : Exception
{
    internal CurrencyMismatchException(Currencies c1, Currencies c2)
        : base($"This operation cannot be performed between {c1} and {c2}.")
    { }
}
```

Comment: I agree that this class should not do the rounding (but perhaps may provide methods for it). You probably have business rules that determine when to do rounding (and how the rounding should be done - this can even be different in different regions)

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback. This has been very helpful.

Comment: I would make the `Amount` and `Currency` properties auto-get-only (C#6) if possible, or get-only with a `readonly` backed field if not. You currently have the ability to modify those properties in any method of the struct, but they really should be immutable after construction.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer They started out read-only but that didn't play well with deserialization. That was originally why I created a separate DTO class. That way the Money struct doesn't have to care about whether or not it can be serialized. It felt like overkill. Right now it's immutable from outside the struct. The question is whether that's good enough. Thank for raising that. I'm interested in input on that. Is my "good enough" immutability really good enough, or should I force use of a DTO for serialization so that I can make the fields read only?

Comment: @scott I am frustrated that has to be an either/or proposition due to legacy decisions in the framework itself. I'll go on the side of "good enough" and retract my original opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have already implemented operators for these four methods:

> ```
> public Money Add(decimal add) => new Money(Amount + add, Currency);
>
> public Money Subtract(decimal subtract) => new Money(Amount - subtract, Currency);
>
> public Money Multiply(decimal by) => new Money(Amount * by, Currency);
>
> public Money Divide(decimal by) => new Money(Amount / by, Currency);
> ```

Why do you still need them? On the other hand you could redirect the operators to those methods and call `new Money` only here like

```
public static Money operator +(Money m, decimal d)
{
    return m.Add(d);
}
```

---

> ```
> public int CompareTo(Money other)
> {
>     RequireSameCurrency(this, other);
>     return Amount.CompareTo(other.Amount);
> }
> ```

In addition to `IComparable<Money>` you could implement it also for `IComparable<double>` and redirect all `<>` etc operators to the above methods and have it implemented only once. Then in the actual operator you could use constants for -1, 0, 1 like *lessThen*, *equal* and *greaterThen*. You would also call the `RequireSameCurrency(m1, m2);` method only once by `CompareTo`.

---

> ```
> enum Currencies
> ```

The name of this enum should be singular, we use plural names usually only for enums decorated with the `[Flags]` attribute.

---

Overall I think it's a good implementation.

Comment: The `Add`, `Subtract`, etc. are redundant. I was thinking that they might make it more obvious that the struct supports these operations. But yes, in each of these cases where I have redundant operators or comparisons I should redirect them to a single method to avoid duplication. Thank you

Comment: I picked up the plural convention for enums years ago without knowing why. What you said makes sense to me. Singular or plural indicates a single value or flags, whether it represents a single value or possibly multiple values. I'll make that change. Thanks.

Comment: Comparison to floating points like `double` - sure, makes sense since it's only comparison and not assignment. If someone wants to assign a floating point they will have to do the conversion, but I can add the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed, it seems to me that, since `CompareTo` is basically used for ordering a collection, it shouldn't be wrong to have more than one currency type:

```
public int CompareTo(Money other)
{
    if(other.Currency != Currency)
    {
        return Currency.CompareTo(other.Currency)
    )
    return Amount.CompareTo(other.Amount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely wouldn't want someone to compare different currencies with >, <, etc. But should I allow sorting a collection that contains multiple currencies? Does it imply a > = < comparison? What if I provide a comparer like MoneyComparer.IgnoreCurrency?

Comment: I think it would be conceivable that a trader or an international retail or wholesale operation would have transactions in different currencies and sorting those transactions would be needed.

Comment: You could add a Boolean argument to CompareTo, to use the currency or not,

Comment: They have transactions in different currencies, and they may need to sort them. But a sort order should be meaningful. We know that 1 < 2 and "b" > "a". But without looking at the latest conversion rate we don't know if $1 < 1 euro.

Comment: Here's my conflict: Do I allow an implicit comparison which may appear "wrong" in some scenarios, provide documentation, and allow others to make their own informed choices when sorting? On the other hand, does throwing the `CurrencyMismatchException` create the possibility of an unexpected runtime error? Thinking though that makes me lean toward allowing the comparison. It should be the responsibility of a developer to understand what they're sorting if they're going to write logic that depends on that sort order.

Comment: Adding xml comments is one option

Comment: Yes, those are definitely coming once this is solidified.